# Better understanding of fragment+actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I read a lot of topics here about fragments and actionbars in android.

But I couldn't understand why it not working correctly.

At first I implement a lot of activities and my fragments (fragment would work thx vogella ;)) starts another activites

The structure is loginactivity -> activityA -> activityB -> fragment -> fragmentA/fragmentB -> activity of fragment A/B

In fragment I create my actionbar but if I click on fragmentA my activity of fragment A lost the actionbar?

The question is simple...

How can I create a actionbar on my fragment for all fragment activities?

Next I will try to....
* inheritance -> not working, next I try to implement onCreateOptionMenu
* I set the actionbar in my mainactivity, if that work I will try to hide it on all acitvities

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: That's what I did. I use the ActionBarSherlock library for my actionbar needs and I wrapped SherlockFragmentActivity and I use this wrapping for all of my activities. Now I have an easy to use action bar that interacts well with my application.

Comment: Agree with @AedonEtLIRA : Download Jack Wharton's ActionBarSherlock project and use SherlockFragmentActivity and then just do getSupportActionBar() method call